# What will happen if I cancel the credit card with which I booked a flight?

Tags: usa, india, payment-cards, british-airways

I booked a flight from makemytrip using my credit card. I will be travelling in British Airways from India to the US. I am planning to cancel the credit card because I am leaving the country for good. What will happen if I cancel my credit card? Will I need it during the check in?

Comment: From the [British Airways checkin instructions](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/howcheckin/public/en_gb) `If you have booked directly with British Airways, either through ba.com or a British Airways Telephone Sales office, and you paid with your debit/ credit card you must present that debit/ credit card at check-in`. So, depends on exactly how you booked / paid for it

Comment: @Gagravarr I have booked flights online quite a bit (albeit not with British Airways) and have never needed to show my debit/credit card when checking in (nor have I seen anyone else have to do that). What if someone else had booked your flight for you? You couldn't take someone else's credit card with you! I am pretty sure you will be ok just showing your passport and a print out of your booking at check in. You can always check in online as well.

Comment: @emmalgale When booking online with British Airways, you're asked if the person making the booking is the one travelling, if you tick "different person" you won't have to show a card at checkin. If you say "same person", you may (but by no means always) have to. I'd say I probably get asked for the card about 5-10% of the time with BA

Comment: @Gagravarr Oh ok. As I said, I haven't booked online with them before, so wasn't sure. I have travelled a couple of times in the last few years on university funded trips (I am a PhD student), so the department office pay for my flight bookings. Not had any problems with flight check ins, but I have had problems checking in to accommodation. On my recent trip, I had to pay for my own accommodation and claim the money back.

Comment: Why would you cancel your credit card before you leave? A credit card is super useful during travel, in case something goes wrong and you need to pay for things. Just hang onto it until you get set up at your destination, then cancel it.

Comment: I've flown with BA plenty of times to Europe/the USA and have never been asked to show my credit/debit card that I booked with, so I wouldn't bet on it happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presenting the card and running a transaction on the card are different things. I bought some show tickets a while back, changed the card, but kept the old card for ticket pickup. The company just wanted to match the numbers on the transaction to the numbers on the piece of plastic, the transaction was run at the time of purchase.

People change / lose / expire cards every day, and no airline is going to wait until departure to take your money. Just keep the old card after you cancel it.